# Trigger script execution on after apt-get upgrade for a certain package?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, scripts, scheduled

Question:

I have customized an application startup script.
Unfortunately, it gets overwritten every time I do

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

when there is an update available (quite often).

Now I have written a script that makes a backup copy of the original, then modifies the original and merges my changes.

Now my question:
How can I trigger a script execution after a package has been updated ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an init script, you can usually make your tweaks in `/etc/default/$PKG_NAME`. Otherwise, you can use `dpkg-divert` to stop `dpkg` from touching the file.